# MS access reports

Tags: ms-access

I created a report using wizard and while creating I selected 4 columns for ordering data in ascending orders. It asked for 4 columns and chose 4 columns and after creation I want to change the preference of the second column to other one. How can I do that??

I cannot see anything in the report query or anywhere else

Comment: What version of office? You have 2 tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore any ordering in your report's query source.  You can discard your ORDER BY from the query because the Access report will use whatever settings you give it for "Sorting and Grouping" instead.

In Access 2003, with your report in design view, choose View -> Sorting and Group from the Access main menu.  If your version of Access is different, look for a similar option.

Answer (score 0):

I should think its just as quick to re-run the whole report. However you can edit the Query that the report is built on.
Or make a query, then get the report to run from the query, this means you can easily change it.

Comment: In Access reports, the report's Sorting/Grouping settings override any ORDER BY in the report's Recordsource, so this answer is wrong.